# Simple jwt not returning refresh token

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using simple jwt with django rest. However i dont think the config `JWT_AUTH` is working. Because i have set the rotate refresh tokens to true but the `token-api-refresh` url only returns access token while it should also return the refresh.

In the settings.py i have

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'shop',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'corsheaders',
    'django_cleanup'
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ]
}
JWT_AUTH = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(minutes=15),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(days=10),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
}
```

My url patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
    path('api-token-refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view()),
    path("",include("shop.urls"))
]
```

My problem is on the `api-token-refresh` as it only returns the access but according to the simple-jwt documentation if i set `rotate refresh token`  to true then it should also return a refresh token alongside the access one.

Edit :

This is the serializer for the token refresh which obviously can return both tokens

```
class TokenRefreshSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    refresh = serializers.CharField()
    access = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        refresh = RefreshToken(attrs['refresh'])

        data = {'access': str(refresh.access_token)}

        if api_settings.ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS:
            if api_settings.BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION:
                try:
                    # Attempt to blacklist the given refresh token
                    refresh.blacklist()
                except AttributeError:
                    # If blacklist app not installed, `blacklist` method will
                    # not be present
                    pass

            refresh.set_jti()
            refresh.set_exp()

            data['refresh'] = str(refresh)

        return data
```

Comment: Hello! Have you used the `TokenObtainPairView` view for the authentication endpoint? [source](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#:~:text=Also%2C%20in%20your%20root%20urls.py%20file%20(or%20any%20other%20url%20config)%2C%20include%20routes%20for%20Simple%20JWT%E2%80%99s%20TokenObtainPairView%20and%20TokenRefreshView%20views%3A)

Comment: Yes i updated the post so you can see it.

Comment: But you didn't? `api-token-refresh` is mapped to `TokenRefreshView.as_view()` which only serializes the new `access_token`. Maybe you'll want to use  `TokenObtainPairView` on both views? Or some other view which serializes both.

Comment: Was looking at the source code and `TokenObtainPairView` takes only username and password. while `TokenRefresh` takes the token and can return both

Comment: @user655941 yes indeed - I just looked as well and I see the issue. Will update with an answer.

Comment: Apparently JWT_AUTH had changed to SIMPLE_JWT on the docs. As this was an old project it still had JWT_AUTH. Thanks for looking into it just a mistake from my side.

Comment: @user655941 ah - ok, GG. I was about to say: the snippet you posted is even different that the one I found (mine was missing the `access = serializers.ReadOnlyField()` attr).

Answer (score 4):

It's not returning refresh token because you defined simple jwt configurations in :

```
JWT_AUTH = {
           
           }
```

Instead of that you just need to change it with

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False
}
```

as per official [documentations](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#rotate-refresh-tokens)

**ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS**

When set to True, if a refresh token is submitted to the TokenRefreshView, a new refresh token will be returned along with the new access token. This new refresh token will be supplied via a “refresh” key in the JSON response. New refresh tokens will have a renewed expiration time which is determined by adding the timedelta in the REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME setting to the current time when the request is made. If the blacklist app is in use and the BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION setting is set to True, refresh tokens submitted to the refresh view will be added to the blacklist.

Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 4):

use **SIMPLE_JWT** Instead of **JWT_AUTH** and set **ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS** to **True**

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
}
```

other more property

```
'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=1),
'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': True,

'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
'AUDIENCE': None,
'ISSUER': None,
'JWK_URL': None,
'LEEWAY': 0,

'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer'),
'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
'TOKEN_USER_CLASS': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser',

'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
```