# When the refresh token is expired in JWT then how we can alive in the same session?

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt

As the refresh token is expired we have to re-login the user again for new access and refresh token so my question is how we can alive in the same session even after the refresh token is expired?

I have tried this in settings.py

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
   'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(seconds=60),
   'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(seconds=120),
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes basically when we authenticate the user using JWT Authentication we have the Access Token and Refresh Token, Now when the Access Token is expired within the given expiration time then we use Refresh Token to generate new Access Token, Now my question is if the Refresh Token is also expired within the given expiration time then the user will logout from the session right? so is there any provision to stay in same session when the Refresh Token also expires.

Comment: @tjheslin1 Can u please check?

Comment: Can you share any code that you have written? Please do so by editing your question. At the moment it will be difficult for anyone to provide you with a solution.

Comment: Done please check it @tjheslin1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple jwt not returning refresh token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69392216/simple-jwt-not-returning-refresh-token)